# fit straight lines with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

i want to use gnuplot to get fit parameters of a first degree polynomial equation (F(x)=a*x+b) for many curvers. Some of the curves are represented exactly straight lines.

For example if my data look like

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

which can be represented with the f(x)=x (param a=0, b=0).

But the following gnuplot code

```
# regression line
f(x) = a*x + b
fit f(x) './test.dat' u 1:2  via a, b
```

fails to compute fit params giving the message below

```
Singular matrix in Invert_RtR
```

update: It seems that gnuplot does not "crash" if i define the number of iterations for fit function

```
FIT_MAXITER = 1
# regression line
f(x) = a*x + b
fit f(x) './test.dat' u 1:2  via a, b
```

It should be a=1 and b=0. But gnuplot gives

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================

a               = 0.989067         +/- 0.004339     (0.4387%)
b               = 0.0761393        +/- 0.02692      (35.36%)
```

How can i "force" gnuplot compute the correct values of a and b?

Answer (score 4):

I have found two solutions:

1) Add a tiny offset to your fit function:

```
f(x) = a*x + b + 1e-9
```

This prevents the singularity issue, and results in a perfectly correct fit (a = 1, b=-1e-9).

2) Eliminate the b parameter altogether

```
f(x) = a*x
```

This assumes that your fit lines will all go through 0, which may of course not be what you want.

Comment: Any offset will do. The problem is not the exact fit, but the variable b going towards zero.

Answer (score 3):

As I see the problem is probably that `f(x)` can be fitted exactly to the data. If you **add any nonzero value** to any of your data, you get no error. In real life, this exact fitting simply does not occur (you have noise). Anyway, regardless gnuplot says "error during fit", it seems that gnuplot fits the function correctly.

Your solution by adding `FIT_MAXITER = 1` can be a workaround. The higher value you define for FIT_MAXITER, the better fitting you get. But if you give too high value for it, the fitting will be exact (the error will be less than the number precision).

Try to fit `f(x)` on your real data and tell us what you get!

Comment: Wrong, I'm afraid. The problem is that the parameter goes towards zero. For the algorithm to work properly, the parameters must have roughly the same order of magnitude. Gnuplot helps there by prescaling the parameters, but that of course fails  towards zero.

Answer (score 0):

You have a two options, I recommend the first:

- replace your variable `b` by `(b+n)`, and substract the fixed variable n (can be one, or any other arbitrary value that is not very small of very large) from the result afterwards. That way $b$ does not vanish, and the gnuplot algorithm will fit successfully & exit without errormessage. Instead it just shows a notice saying "Hmmmm.... Sum of squared residuals is zero. Can't compute errors."
- give a very small starting value for `b`. Gnuplot prescales its internal representative of $b, that let's the fit converge before the error turns up.

General rule for fitting: You parameters need to be of the same order of magnitude, and be initialised to be of the correct order of magnitude.